# Why is my ng2 validator wrapping my validation messages in `\n`?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Implementing the iterative [error-text-accumulation pattern from the angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html), I accumulate all the messages from my custom form validators into a single string to display to the user:

```
onValueChanged(data?: any) {
  if (!this.heroForm) { return; }
  const form = this.heroForm.form;

  for (const field in this.formErrors) {
    // clear previous error message (if any)
    this.formErrors[field] = '';
    const control = form.get(field);

    if (control && control.dirty && !control.valid) {
      const messages = this.validationMessages[field];
      for (const key in control.errors) {
        this.formErrors[field] += messages[key] + '\n';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Our design calls for these to appear without any list decoration as multi-line text below the input field.

Using the above function, and logging just before the closing brace, I see what I expect my string to contain:

```
password1: "Must contain an uppercase character.↵Must contain a special character.↵Must contain a numeric character.↵
```

However, by the time it reaches the template, it becomes this:

```
<div _ngcontent-xoo-4="" class="error-message-field">
                            Must contain an uppercase character.
Must contain a special character.
Must contain a numeric character.

</div>
```

Because I am using

```
.error-message-field {
  height: auto;
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

I get an extra line above and below my field error.

Where do these two extra `\n` come from? I don't manipulate the resultant string anywhere else myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a silly mistake, in the end. The initial tab (`\t`) gave it away.

I have configured my IDE's beautifier perhaps to aggressively. The line breaks came from the template:

```
<div *ngIf="formErrors.password1" class="error-message-field">
    {{ formErrors.password1 }}
</div>
```

I assumed the HTML minifier would have removed these extra line-breaks and whitespace from around the value. Looking at Source (rather than the Devtools Elements tree) made it more obvious.